# vector of vectors of polymorphic classes - possible to nest boost pointer containers?

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, nested, containers

Is it feasible to nest boost pointer containers? Is it a bad idea? (I'm using C++ in MS Visual Studio Community 2013).

I would like to set up a vector of vectors of polymorphic classes and I want to make sure the memory management is handled as simply as possible.  I have studied examples such as [Thorsten Ottosen's farm example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/examples.html).

My application is essentially the same as his code except that I need to take the farm class and create a new class which holds a vector (or deque) of farms.  I suspect I will hit unintended consequences when I do this. (I'm still learning C++ and this is my first real project.)

Comment: Why do you need vector of vectors?

Comment: Why would you not be able to nest pointer containers. Have you tried?

Comment: Referring again to Thorsten Ottosen's farm example, I need to be able to iterate over a large number of farms, where each farm is a class with a iterable container of assorted animals.  The various animals are polymorphic classes.  This should let me iterate over farms or iterate over animals within any farm and then work with farm-specific or animal-specific metadata as needed.

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear what's being asked". You could salvage this question, maybe, by showing **exactly** what you'd like to be able to do. Write it it in "wish code". If you must.